# connect to mysql in a loop

Tags: python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

i have to connect to mysql server and grab some data for ever

so i have two way

1)connect to mysql the grab data in a while

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='localhost',database='db',charset='utf8',autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
while True:
  cursor.execute("statments")
  sqlData = cursor.fetchone()
  print(sqlData)
  sleep(0.5)
```

this working good but if script crashed due to mysql connection problem script goes down

2)connect to mysql in while

```
while True:
   try:
      conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='localhost',database='db',charset='utf8',autocommit=True)
      cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
      cursor.execute("statments")
      sqlData = cursor.fetchone()
      print(sqlData)
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()
      sleep(0.5)
   except:
      print("recoverable error..")
```

both code working good but my question is which is better?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among these two, better way will be to use a single connection but create a new cursor for each statement because creation of new connection takes time but creating a new cursor is fast. You may update the code as:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='localhost',database='db',charset='utf8',autocommit=True)
while True:
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute("statments")
        sqlData = cursor.fetchone()
        print(sqlData)
    except Exception: # Catch exception which will be raise in connection loss

        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='localhost',database='db',charset='utf8',autocommit=True)
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

    finally:
        cursor.close()

conn.close()    # Close the connection
```

Also read [*Defining Clean-up Actions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) regarding the usage of `try:finally` block.

Comment: good,but what can i do for connection losses?! for example mysql crash on high load ,,your code dont start working after the mysql back normal because the connection left!

Comment: If there will high load, even creating a new connection won't work. Your entire application will go down. Isn't it?

Comment: in second code i can ignore error with try...except and after mysql server back online it will try re connecting easily but in first code or your code cant ignore errors...

Comment: I missed the *forever* part. Updated the answer

Comment: your except Exception code just run once!? 
also what is the job of finally? while true never finish! :)

Comment: It is the part of `while`, it will handle each query execution within while loops . `finally` will be executed with/wit-out exception i.e, even if there is exception or not your cursor connection will be close.